# Why is my component not importing inside App.vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to show the pulse loader during page load.
I'm getting two errors from the code below.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to='/'><div v-if="$route.name=='home'" class='activeLink'>Home</div></router-link>
      <pulse-loader :loading=this.loading></pulse-loader>
    </div>
    <keep-alive include="home">  </keep-alive>
    <router-view />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PulseLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
    components: {
      PulseLoader
  }
  },
  methods: {
    getLoadingStatus() {
      $(window).on('load', function(){
        this.loading=false;
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getLoadingStatus()
  },
};
</script>
```

errors:

```
Unknown custom element: <pulse-loader> - did you register the component correctly

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

This is in an otherwise vanilla vue.js project created from the vue cli.

Comment: I think your path can be wrong 'vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue'. Try put just "./PulseLoader.vue", if you component are in the same place of App.vue

Comment: Check the path 'vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue'. If you are sure that is correct can you please post the code of that file?

Comment: And about "ReferenceError: $ is not defined", you not have jQuery defined on your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

registering components is not done in data, rather on it's own.

```
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
    components: {
      PulseLoader
     }
  },
```

Should be changed to:

```
  components: {
      'pulse-loader': PulseLoader  // name the component here what you want to name your custom tag
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your tag to `<PulseLoader>`. Either that or

```
components: {
  pulseLoader: PulseLoader
}
```

My understanding is that Vue will translate camelCase to kebab-case, but it will not translate PascalCase to kebab-case.

Also it looks like you need jQuery (`$ is not defined`)